# How to upload multiple images to db in php

Tags: javascript, php, image

I want to upload a multiple file at a time and it will be store into DB.How can i do it?

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 
    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) 
    {//loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 1000000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) 
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path))
                {//if file moved to uploads folder
                    echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
                } 
                else 
                {//if file was not moved.

                    echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
                }
        } 
        else 
        {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

When i am trying to upload a file and the uploaded file is there in local folder /uploads.But here how can i get the name of file that's in loacal folder /uploads for storing purpose.

Comment: How about: `$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this coding:

**multiupload.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Multiple Images Using jquery and PHP</title>
<!-------Including jQuery from Google ------>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<!------- Including CSS File ------>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="formdiv">
<h2>Multiple Image Upload Form</h2>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
First Field is Compulsory. Only JPEG,PNG,JPG Type Image Uploaded. Image Size Should Be Less Than 100KB.
<div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div>
<input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
</form>
<!------- Including PHP Script here ------>
<?php include "connect.php"; ?>
<?php include "upload.php"; ?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php include "connect.php"; ?>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.
$target_path = "uploads/";     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
// Loop to get individual element from the array
$validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png","pdf","gif","doc","docx","txt","bmp");      // Extensions which are allowed.
$ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));   // Explode file name from dot(.)
$file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.
//$target_path = $target_path . md5(md5(uniqid())) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
$j = $j + 1;      // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 20000000)     // Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
&& in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i])) {

    //if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) { <!----For file uploading with actual name->

// If file moved to uploads folder.
echo $imagename=basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
echo $imagetmp="uploads/" . $imagename;

//Insert the image name and image content in image_table
$insert_image="INSERT INTO `image_table`(`image_name`, `image_content`) VALUES('$imagetmp','$imagename')";

mysql_query($insert_image);


echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
} else {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
echo "not inserted in db";
echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
}
} else {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
}


}

}
?>
```

**script.js**

```
var abc = 0;      // Declaring and defining global increment variable.
$(document).ready(function() {
//  To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed.
$('#add_more').click(function() {
$(this).before($("<div/>", {
id: 'filediv'
}).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
name: 'file[]',
type: 'file',
id: 'file'
}), $("<br/><br/>")));
});
// Following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file.
$('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
abc += 1; // Incrementing global variable by 1.
var z = abc - 1;
var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
$(this).before("<div id='abcd" + abc + "' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
$(this).hide();
$("#abcd" + abc).append($("<img/>", {
id: 'img',
src: 'x.jpg',
alt: 'delete'
}).click(function() {
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
}));
}
});
// To Preview Image
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
$('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
};
$('#upload').click(function(e) {
var name = $(":file").val();
if (!name) {
alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
e.preventDefault();
}
});
});
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
mysql_select_db("demo")or die("cannot select DB");
?>
```

**style.css**

```
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans";
form{
background-color:#fff
}
#maindiv{
width:960px;
margin:10px auto;
padding:10px;
font-family:'Droid Sans',sans-serif
}
#formdiv{
width:500px;
float:left;
text-align:center
}
form{
padding:40px 20px;
box-shadow:0 0 10px;
border-radius:2px
}
h2{
margin-left:30px
}
.upload{
background-color:red;
border:1px solid red;
color:#fff;
border-radius:5px;
padding:10px;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 green;
box-shadow:2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
}
.upload:hover{
cursor:pointer;
background:#c20b0b;
border:1px solid #c20b0b;
box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
}
#file{
color:green;
padding:5px;
border:1px dashed #123456;
background-color:#f9ffe5
}
#upload{
margin-left:45px
}
#noerror{
color:green;
text-align:left
}
#error{
color:red;
text-align:left
}
#img{
width:17px;
border:none;
height:17px;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-bottom:91px
}
.abcd{
text-align:center
}
.abcd img{
height:100px;
width:100px;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #e8debd
}
b{
color:red
}
```

Comment: how to insert a all image name in single row..??

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy